# getResource returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, gradle, resources

I'm trying to get two resource files called `config.yml` and `messages.yml`, but it's not working. I made a project to test with just a file called `text.txt` located in `resources/files/test.txt`.

Like this:
[image]

My code is:

```
package be.isach.tests;

import java.io.File;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        for(File file : obj.getFile("files/").listFiles())
            System.out.println(file.getName());
    }

    private File getFile(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        return new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
    }

}
```

When I run it from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), it runs well and prints:
"test.txt".

But when I run it in the compiled jar, built with "gradle build", it just doesn't work, and returns a NPE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at be.isach.tests.Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

Here's my `build.gradle` (external link not to have a too big question post) if it can help fixing all that:
  http://pastebin.com/gY4NPx8t

I tried a lot of things, such as; `Thread.currentThread()` and more. I searched for over 2 hours on the internet, but have found nothing that actually works.

If you're wondering, yes, it puts resources in the Jar:
I can't put any more links.

Thanks in advance,
Sacha.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not putting the `resources` into the compiled JAR. Can you open the JAR File and check if `files` Directory and the Text File in it exists?

If not, then you'll need to change your Gradle Script to start putting the resources into the compiled JAR.

Also, try to prefix the path with `/` in order to access the resources in the root directory. If you are not doing it, then you are just looking at package level, relative to the current package.

Change it as follows:

```
obj.getFile("/files").listFiles()
```

Also, change the `getResource()` method to `getResourceAsStream()` as follows:

```
private InputStream getFile(String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    return classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}
```

Comment: It exists, but not in a resources directory. Directly in the archive, at same level than the be folder:

http://prntscr.com/9wzfbb

Comment: Now getting an different NPE at Line 15:
return new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

Comment: Use `getResourceAsStream()`. Also, can you please share the output of `System.out.println(file.getName());`?

Comment: I tried like this:
`return new File(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName).getFile());`

As you asked, but getFile() can't be found. I know it's basic, but I never had to use them yet so I don't really know what to do ^^

Comment: It prints file.getName(), but I can't read it with a Scanner for example. :/

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Please try now.

Comment: thanks, It returns an InputStream that doesn't seem to be = to null :) but what I'd like is getting the File as the API I use for reading YAML reads only files. Any way to get that?

Comment: You can use `return new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).toURI());`

Comment: When your resources are bundled in the JAR/WAR then you should be using `getResourceAsStream()`. `getResource()` will work if you are running your Application from Eclipse/IntelliJ or you are reading a File that is present on the Disk and not bundled within the JAR/WAR.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How can I then use the file? Because I need it as a File for the API I use. ^^

Comment: Write your `InputStream` to a file and then access it from there.

Comment: InputStream.read() seems to cause a new NPE.

I finally chose to use PrintWriters to write my YAML files as getResource methods don't seem to work and now that I've been stuck on that for 3 days, I need to find another solution. Thanks a lot for your help about this!